# Python: .png image file that wont open because of text before file signature

Tags: python, png

I have a large series of png files that have had some text added before the ‰PNG file signature. I'm trying to find a way of opening the files in python and deleting the extra text before writing to a new file, so I can view the images.

A screenshot from Notepad++ of the file can be seen in the below image to give a better understanding of the problem.

[first few lines of file showing additional text before file signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H32AX.jpg)

So far I have tried this code

```
infile = open('radar0.1.107652907', encoding='ANSI')
outfile = open('test.png', 'w', encoding='ANSI')

imagetext = infile.read()

pos = imagetext.find('‰')

outtext = imagetext[pos:]

outfile.write(imagetext)
```

But when I try and open the new file it wont open.

Any help would be massively appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the ending of the file and the file data itself is ok?

Comment: Don't open the file as text with an encoding. That is likely to affect sequences that look like line endings. Open as binary.

Comment: Thank you @BoarGules working in binary solved my issue. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using @BoarGules suggestion to work in binary. Code is below

```
infile = open('radar0.1.107652907', 'rb')
outfile = open('test.png', 'wb')

imagetext = infile.read()

pos = imagetext.find(b'\x89PNG')

outtext = imagetext[pos:]

outfile.write(outtext)


infile.close()
outfile.close()
```